# Project Euler: Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product

Tags: c++

I haven't been able to get this to work but I'm not sure where the problem lie.
The answer should be 23514624000. This prints 2144416768.

Update: Got it working. Thanks for the help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    long long prod = 0;
    long long maxProd = 0;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length()-12; i++){
        prod = static_cast<long long>(str[i]-'0')*(str[i+1]-'0')*(str[i+2]-'0')*(str[i+3]-'0')*(str[i+4]-'0')*(str[i+5]-'0')*(str[i+6]-'0')*(str[i+7]-'0')*(str[i+8]-'0')*(str[i+9]-'0')*(str[i+10]-'0')*(str[i+11]-'0')*(str[i+12]-'0');
        if(prod > maxProd){
            maxProd = prod;
        }
    }
    cout << maxProd << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `str[i*4]` is not like the others. `str[i*4]` just doesn't belong

Answer (score 1):

- Multiplication of 13 1-digit numbers (can be upto 2,541,865,828,329) may not fit in typical `unsigned int` (32-bit long, the maximum value is 4,294,967,295). You should use `long long` instead.
- Typically the character codes are not the same as the numbers that the characters represents. You have to convert between them.
- The condition `i <= str.length()-12` is wrong. `str[i+12]` will be out-of-range when `i = str.length()-12`. It should be `i < str.length()-12`.

Fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    long long prod = 0;
    long long maxProd = 0;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < str.length()-12; i++){
        prod = static_cast<long long>(str[i]-'0')*(str[i+1]-'0')*(str[i+2]-'0')*(str[i+3]-'0')*(str[i+4]-'0')*(str[i+5]-'0')*(str[i+6]-'0')*(str[i+7]-'0')*(str[i+8]-'0')*(str[i+9]-'0')*(str[i+10]-'0')*(str[i+11]-'0')*(str[i+12]-'0');
        if(prod > maxProd){
            maxProd = prod;
            cout << maxProd << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 unsigned int maxProd = 0;
```

The maximum value of this unsigned int will not be able to contain such a large number, using a `long long` will be able to hold such a number.